# rails 5 left outer join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

Need Clarification about left outer joins.
I have a model named CLub

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :club_members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

another model named ClubMember

```
class ClubMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :club
end
```

When I run a query like

```
Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members)
```

it gives me all record from lett table

But with something like

```
Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members).where('club_members.is_assigned =?',true)
```

Its returning only those entries which exist in ClubMember,
I was expecting it to return entries from left table which don't exist in ClubMember & existing entries in ClubMember with status TRUE too.
Just leave those entries which exist in ClubMemebr with status FALSE.

I have a wrong concept or doing something wrong?

Comment: yes. left join returns null value from the right table for the records where right table has not any records. But you are getting the values where is_assigned = true. You also need to apply the condition that it should also return the records where is_assigned = null.

Comment: no entry with is_assigned - null exist in ClubMember, what is_assigned = null is going to do here?

Comment: I am not sure about Ruby on Rails. But i think, this would work for your problem. 
Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members).where("club_members.is_assigned =true OR club_members.is_assigned is null")

Comment: Yes its working, but can you clarify little that whats happening here

Comment: just posted details below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**LEFT JOIN:**

> The **LEFT JOIN** returns all rows from the left table, even if there
>   are no matches in the right table.

This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in the right table; the join will still return a row in the result, but with NULL in each column from the right table.

So if we apply the condition on any column in right table. Then it will returns the results according to the condition. If we want the records where there is notmatch. Than we should add a condition where right table has null values also. That's what i have added in the code.

```
Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members)
    .where("club_members.is_assigned =true OR club_members.is_assigned is null")
```

Comment: My actual quey is Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members).where.not('club_members.is_assigned =? ',true)   NOT is really important here. Can you tell me that how to use is NULL thing now?

Comment: Try this:  Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members).where("club_members.is_assigned != true OR club_members.is_assigned is null")

Comment: Sorry. i think, you no need to use the null case here because query will always returns the records where is_assigned not equal to true. Are you not getting the null results in this case?

Comment: above Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members).where("club_members.is_assigned != true OR club_members.is_assigned is null") is working fine.
Giving me null records too

Comment: `OR null` is the important part!

Answer (score 0):

For return the left side plus the coincidences you could add an `OR`. something like this:

```
Club.left_outer_joins(:club_members).where('club_members.is_assigned =?',true).or(where('condition with the left side'))
```